# How to prevent a data access method from being called directly

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm developing a WPF application and I'm wondering if it is possible to prevent access to a specific procedure unless it has been called by another procedure. Specifically, I have a delete procedure in my data access layer that I only want to be run if certain validation procedures have already been performed. I don't want to perform the validation procedures in the delete method because the validation logic can differ depending on the situation it is being called in.

I have my application architected as follows:
Data Access - Entity Framework
Data Repository - Fairly generic CRUD operations. Only layer with a dependency of the Data Access Layer
Business Logic - For complex business logic.
Presentation - Either makes a call to the business logic layer or if it is simple data access then the data repository layer. I didn't force this layer to go through the BL layer since I have a lot of data access that would be a straight pass-through and I didn't want to do that.

Basically what I'm looking for is something like this
UI -> Validation Method (BL) -> Delete Method (Repository)
UI -> Delete Method -> Exception is thrown

I fairly new to developing multi-layered applications and the .net framework, so I'm looking for the best approach to take here. I was looking at code access security and it looks like placing a deny on the Delete method and then using an assert in the validation method to override it would do what I'm looking for. I'm a little cautious around using security attributes for that so I wanted to see if that was a good option of if there might be a better way of handling this.

Note: In case it matters to anyone, I am programming in VB.Net, but I can translate from C# fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you are implementing a layered architecture, each layer should be a different project in your solution, then you can simply remove the dependency from the first layer to the third, with that, it will be completely impossible to bypass the second layer.

Comment: I don't want to remove the dependency on the Data Repository layer from my presentation layer. Otherwise, I would need to write a lot of additional procedures to pass the data through the business logic layer to the presentation layer (and possibly back up through the business logic layer).